# DOT node with no left-hand-side

Tags: java, hibernate, jinq

I'm using jinq version 1.8.11 with hibernate version 4.3
Using hibernate session factory and not entity manager.

I'm trying the following query:

```
JPAJinqStream<Routine> routineStream = stream.streamAll(getCurrentSession(), Routine.class);

    if (text.isPresent()) {
        final String searchText = text.get();
        routineStream = routineStream
                .leftOuterJoin(
                        (r, source) -> source.stream(NLSProperty.class),
                        (r, nls) -> nls.getVarKey().equals("routine.100.title")
                ).select(pair -> pair.getOne());"%" + searchText + "%")).select(Pair::getOne);
    }
    List<Routine> tp = routineStream.toList();
```

When the variable text is not present the query works and I get results.
When the variable text is present I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong?

I have debug the jinq and the query it's generating looks like this:

```
SELECT A FROM de.etherapists.ehealth.model.routine.Routine A LEFT OUTER JOIN de.etherapists.ehealth.model.NLSProperty B ON B.varKey = 'routine.100.title';
```

Thanks

Comment: The resulting query String JOIN does not contain a Link between A and B. I think this is what Hibernate complains about. What is the query you would actually expect? How do your Entity classes look like (especially the foreign key definitions).

Comment: Hi,
The entities aren't contected with onetomany or manytomany annotations.
The query I expect would look like this

SELECT * FROM routines r
left outer JOIN nlsproperties n ON n.varKey = CONCAT('routine.', r.id, '.title');

Comment: Never saw a `concat` within a `join` condition - is that legit at all? (really not sure). How about `select * from routines r, nslproperties n where n.varKey = CONCAT('routine.', r.id, '.title');` ?

Comment: well I can also change the query to be something like
[SELECT * FROM routines r
left JOIN nlsproperties n ON n.varKey = r.title;]

since the query you suggested giving me wrong results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I upgraded hibernate version to 5.1
Still using the session factory and not entity manager.

and the code is now:

```
if (text.isPresent()) {
        routineStream = routineStream
                .leftOuterJoin(
                        (routine, source) -> source.stream(NLSProperty.class),
                        (routine, nls) -> routine.getTitle().equals(nls.getVarKey())
                )
                .where(pair -> JPQL.like(pair.getOne().getShortCode(), "%" + text + "%")
                        || JPQL.like(pair.getTwo().getVarValue(), "%" + text + "%"))
                .select(Pair::getOne)
    }
```

and it works like a charm